# How do I enable a user to change their password on AWS using Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, permissions, terraform

I have a group I defined in Terraform:

```
resource "aws_iam_group" "developers" {
  name = "developers"
}
```

and I have some permissions added to it:

```
resource "aws_iam_group_policy_attachment" "cloudwatch_readonly_access" {
  group      = aws_iam_group.developers.name
  policy_arn = arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/CloudWatchReadOnlyAccess
}
```

and I'd like to add the option for the user to change their password. The docs say that I need to do this:

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iam:GetAccountPasswordPolicy",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iam:ChangePassword",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::account-id-without-hyphens:user/${aws:username}"
    }
  ]
}
```

but I'm not sure what would be the best course of action to do this. The docs say that I can just paste the JSON into the `policy` object:

```
resource "aws_iam_group_policy_attachment" "password_change" {
  group      = aws_iam_group.developers.name
  policy     = "{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "iam:GetAccountPasswordPolicy",
        "Resource": "*"
      },
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "iam:ChangePassword",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::account-id-without-hyphens:user/${aws:username}"
      }
    ]
  }"
}
```

but then I can't substitute the account-id from a variable (`account-id-without-hyphens`). How can I do this properly?

Answer (score 1):

Typically, when using a multiline string in terraform, you would use the heredoc syntax:

```
resource "aws_iam_group_policy_attachment" "password_change" {
    group      = aws_iam_group.developers.name
    policy     = <<-EOT
        {
            "Version": "2012-10-17",
            "Statement": [
                {
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Action": "iam:GetAccountPasswordPolicy",
                    "Resource": "*"
                },
                {
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Action": "iam:ChangePassword",
                    "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::account-id-without-hyphens:user/$${aws:username}"
                }
            ]
        }
    EOT
}
```

That syntax fully supports terraform interpolation, so you'll need to escape your IAM interpolation with a double $$. You can pull in your account name with a statement like:

```
 data "aws_caller_identity" "current" {}
```

Which will let you get your account ID from `${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}`

Heredoc literals can get hairy if you have a lot of them with heavy use of interpolation. If you've got a lot of IAM policies to write, use [the iam_policy_document data resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/iam_policy_document). That style is more visible to tools like tfsec, and lets you use features like dynamic blocks.